# Remove Null Columns and combine Rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have data in table like

```
ID            desc             Year   pid
0006845503    tes1             null   null
0006845503    null             2017   null      
0006845503    null             null    90   
0006845503    tes2             null    null
0006845503    null             2018    null
0006845503    null             null    100
```

I want the result like

```
ID            desc             year   pid
0006845503    tes1             2017   90
0006845503    tes2             2018   100
```

Used Max function it will return only one row. i want this to be working on a dynamic way. Please help

Comment: you want to remove IDs with null values right ?

Comment: please check my data its all the same id

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any records with null value then

ex: `select * from table where column_name is not null`

If you don't want NULL value then use ISNULL function

ex: `select isnull(col_name,'') from table`

Comment: what is this bro, with the where condition i can achieve what i asked.